# Set max value for each label with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm working with Chart.js and it's awesome, but I have a problem, I made this Radar Chart with Chart.js

[image: Radar Chart]

As you see, the values that I have are very scattered so I need to set a max value for each label, is there a way to do this?

This is my code:

```
  @data = {
      labels: ["Health", "Phyisical Attack", "Magic Attack", "Phyisical Armor", "Magic Armor  "],
      datasets: [
          {
              label: "My First dataset",
              fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
              pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              data: [@health_growth[0], @physical_attack_growth[0], @magic_attack_growth[0], @physical_armor_growth[0], @magic_armor_growth[0]]
          },
      ]
  };
  @options = {}
```

Thanks.

**Edit:** Ok, I see that scaleSteps, scaleStepWidth and scaleStartValue can do the job, but I need to set those values for each label, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just scale the values and then divide by the scaling factor before you show the respective tooltip

```
var scaling = [10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1];
var data = {
    labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [5, 5, 9, 81, 56, 55, 40].map(function (e, i) {
                return e * scaling[i];
            })
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx).Radar(data, {
    tooltipTemplate: function (valueObject) {
        return valueObject.value / scaling[data.labels.indexOf(valueObject.label)];
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cq1q5wuf/